# Javascript string.length and string.lastIndexOf diff values

Tags: javascript, html

To simplify my question, let's say I have the following script:

```
var sPath = "/page/script/";
if (sPath.length != sPath.lastIndexOf("/"))
    sPath = sPath + '/';
// do something else
```

Why it's not getting into the conditional? Why it's a diff value?

Comment: lastIndexOf is a really bad way to test the last character of a string. Either use a regexp as Vivin suggests or alternatively `if (sPath.slice(-1) != "/")` also works.

Comment: Bad way indeed, but my real question was why aren't they same, but thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: I understand, that's why I replied with what I hope is a helpful comment rather than as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `sPath.length` is `13`, but the last char of this is string (and the `lastIndexOf('/')`) is the `12th`, because Javascript vectors goes from `0` to `n`.

For example, the string "ABC" has a length of `3`, but its positions are `0`, `1` and `2`.

However, this should work:

```
var sPath = "/page/script/";
if ((sPath.length-1) != sPath.lastIndexOf("/"))
    sPath = sPath + '/';
```

JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zGyAa/

Answer (score 2):

The direct solution to your question is what xvatar posted.

But instead of comparing the length to the last index, you can use a regular expression to check if the last character is `/`:

```
if(/\/$/.test(path)) {
   ...
}
```

This is a little more obvious and cleaner IMHO.

Another thing, please consider using braces around your `if` statements, even if they are one-liners. It's remarkably easy to create all kinds of frustrating bugs. For example, if you have:

```
if(somecondition) 
   dosomething();
```

Then someone comes along later and adds:

```
if(somecondition) 
   dosomething();
   dosomethingelse();
```

The second function call won't get called. Of course, it seems obvious now, but this can cause a significant amount of hair-pulling before you finally find out what went wrong. When you add braces, it makes your code consistent and you can easily tell what code belongs inside the `if`, and what doesn't.

Comment: This is a prettier solution, a single check instead of two

Comment: An good solution indeed, but my real question was why aren't they same, even tho, +1 for that elegant and fast answer!

Answer (score 1):

it should be `if ((sPath.length - 1) != sPath.lastIndexOf("/"))`

in almost all the default context of programming, the largest index is the length - 1

Answer (score 0):

Off by one! `.length` is not zero based, `(last)indexOf` is

So the index of the last character is `.length - 1`